# Whether "Lord Jesus" is common in use?

Tags: word-usage

I'm wondering whether "Lord Jesus" in which the definite article "the" is missing is common in English? I see someone use "Lords Jesus " in a translation. For example,"**Lord Jesus** said, '**But of that day and hour knoweth no man, no, not the angels of heaven, but my Father only.**'" I thought "the Lord Jesus" is more common. and I'm wondering if "Lord Jesus" without the definite article is acceptable in English culture. Looking forward to your reply. Thank you.

Comment: What research have you done and what does that research tell you? Please update the post with this information.

Comment: In America, no one would use either one except in an exclusively religious context, and the specific usage would vary from cult to cult. Specificity of liturgical references is a matter of ingroup solidarity, and one should follow the local custom, whatever it is.

Comment: Thank you for your patient reply. In fact, I'm wondering whether "Lord Jesus" in which the definite article "the" is missing is common in English? For example,"Lord Jesus said, 'But of that day and hour knoweth no man, no, not the angels of heaven, but my Father only.'" Could you share more? Thank you.

Comment: It varies from one religious community to another.  Some communities will almost always include "the", others will almost always exclude "the".  In my anecdotal experience, including the article is more common, but leaving it out is not at all rare.

Comment: Thank you all guys for the answers. They are beneficial. I come to understand the usage, Thank you.

Comment: @JohnLawler I would have said almost the opposite: I can't think of many other places than the US where you would actually be likely to hear either version _outside_ of strictly religious contexts.

Comment: I would expect people to refer to *the Lord Jesus* except when they were addressing him in prayer, as in: *Lord Jesus, we ask you......*

Comment: It's highly dependent on the religious convictions of the speaker.

Comment: @JohnLawler - Actually, there are those in the US who would use "Lord Jesus" as a swear word of sorts:  "Lord Jesus!  Where did you find such an ugly shirt?"

Answer (score 0):

Only if addressing Jesus Himself does it seem natural.  That is,

> Amen. Come, Lord Jesus. (Rev 20:22)

but not

> May Lord Jesus come.

There are tons of Biblical references to "our Lord Jesus" and "the Lord Jesus" when He is referred to in the third person ([link](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=%22lord%20jesus%22%20site:biblegateway.com&*)).  I can't find references to "Lord Jesus" in the third person elsewhere, either.  Just one of those things, I suppose.

Come to think of it, it's not just this title (Lord) that shows this pattern.  We'd refer to the Senator, the colonel, the doctor, but we would speak to them directly as Senator, Colonel, Doctor.